# Getting "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null"

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**Main.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/listModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:weather_app/model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var listModel;

  bool circular = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
  void getData() async {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2295420/'));
    var r = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      listModel = ListModel.fromJson({"data": r});
      print(listModel);
      circular = false;
    });
    //
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('WEATHER REPORT'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: circular ? CircularProgressIndicator(): ListView.builder(itemCount: listModel.consolidatedWeather.length,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)=>
          dataShow(listModel.consolidatedWeather[index],index)),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget dataShow(Model obj, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.teal,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Name ${index + 1} : ${obj.weatherStateName}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                "PhoneNumber : ${obj.theTemp}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**List Model.dart**

```
import 'package:weather_app/model.dart';

class ListModel {
  ListModel({
     required this.consolidatedWeather,
  });

  List<Model> consolidatedWeather;

  factory ListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListModel(
    consolidatedWeather: List<Model>.from(json["consolidated_weather"].map((x) => Model.fromJson(x))).toList(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "consolidated_weather": List<dynamic>.from(consolidatedWeather.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
```

**Model.dart**

```
class Model {
  Model({
    required this.weatherStateName,
    required this.weatherStateAbbr,
    required this.applicableDate,
    required this.theTemp,
  });

  String weatherStateName;
  String weatherStateAbbr;
  DateTime applicableDate;
  double theTemp;

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
    weatherStateName: json["weather_state_name"],
    weatherStateAbbr: json["weather_state_abbr"],
    applicableDate: DateTime.parse(json["applicable_date"]),
    theTemp: json["the_temp"].toDouble(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "weather_state_name": weatherStateName,
    "weather_state_abbr": weatherStateAbbr,
    "applicable_date": "${applicableDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${applicableDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${applicableDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
    "the_temp": theTemp,
  };
}
```

**pupspec.yml**

```
name: weather_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  meta: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**ERROR**

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Redmi Note 9 Pro...
Restarted application in 1,965ms.
E/flutter (26913): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (26913): Receiver: null
E/flutter (26913): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Model)
E/flutter (26913): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (26913): #1      new ListModel.fromJson (package:weather_app/listModel.dart:11:72)
E/flutter (26913): #2      _MyAppState.getData.<anonymous closure> (package:weather_app/main.dart:30:29)
E/flutter (26913): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1088:30)
E/flutter (26913): #4      _MyAppState.getData (package:weather_app/main.dart:29:5)
E/flutter (26913): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26913): 
W/Choreographer(26913): Frame time is 0.009381 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
W/Choreographer(26913): Frame time is 0.021302 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
W/Choreographer(26913): Frame time is 0.006804 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
W/Choreographer(26913): Frame time is 0.064763 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
```

What can I try next to resolve this?

Comment: Hi! you passed json without 'consolidated_weather' field to `ListModel.fromJson`. Pay attention to this: `listModel = ListModel.fromJson({"data": r});` and this `List<Model>.from(json["consolidated_weather"].map((x) => Model.fromJson(x))).toList()`

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand

Comment: If above is wrong what would be the model class for below json                                           {
   "consolidated_weather":[
      {
         "weather_state_name":"Heavy Rain",
         "weather_state_abbr":"hr",
         "applicable_date":"2021-07-19",
         "the_temp":25.11,
         
      }
]
}

Comment: try to use `listModel = ListModel.fromJson(r);` instead `listModel = ListModel.fromJson({"data": r});`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

The getData() fn should go like this..

```
 void getData() async {
 var res = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2295420/'));
 var r = json.decode(res.body);
 setState(() {
  listModel = ListModel.fromJson(r); // Change this line
  print(listModel);
  circular = false;
 });
 }
```